# How to acces array in laravel

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, laravel-blade

So this a really newbie question but I need a better understanding of how does work Laravel and PHP.

I'd like to access an array from the blade with something like `{{$article->title}}` or `{{$article['title']}}`

The only way I found it was to create an `stdClass()` and attribute each of the value of the array to the new object.

```
    $article = new \stdClass();

    $article->id = "";
    $article->title = "";
    $article->content = "";
    $article->created_at = "";
    $article->updated_at = "";

    if($var != null){
        $tmp = DB::select('select * from articles where id = ' . $var);
        $article->id = $tmp[0]->id;
        $article->title = $tmp[0]->title;
        $article->content = $tmp[0]->content;
        $article->created_at = $tmp[0]->created_at;
        $article->updated_at = $tmp[0]->updated_at;
    }
```

However this is pretty ugly and I'd like to know what is the proper way of doing it.

I tried to keep it simple with

```
$article = DB::select('select * from articles where id = ' . $var);
```

But I dont find a way to access `$article` in my blade template.

This is the `var_dump` of it :

```
array (size=1)
  0 => 
    object(stdClass)[170]
      public 'id' => int 1
      public 'title' => string 'Test' (length=4)
      public 'content' => string '<p>Test</p>' (length=151)
      public 'created_at' => string '2016-12-21 10:00:04' (length=19)
      public 'updated_at' => string '2016-12-21 10:15:57' (length=19)
```

Comment: $article = $tmp[0]; would simplify your example above. But ->first() would also be more correct as Alexey suggests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend you to learn [Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent) and [Collections](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/collections). It's the proper way. Using these you can simply get the data:

```
$article = Article::where('id', $var)->first();
```

Then pass `$article` to the view and access it with:

```
{{ $article->title }}
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Explainations

Laravel is really intuitive. Think of it as if it was something from the real life. You ask your intern to deliver all the articles. You have now all the articles and you can now proceed on displaying them in your paperwork.

This is mostly the same with Laravel. You ask the facade `DB` to deliver you **ALL THE ARTICLES**. You will then cast the result in a variable most of the time. So your variable should be named `$articles` and not `$article`.

Then, you can use the `@foreach ()` syntax in Laravel Blade to iterate through all your articles. It's really that simple and intuitive. Just work like if you were in the real world asking something. That's how Laravel has been conceived.

So, for each articles that the facade got you (only one), you'll have to make something out of it.

There is a great (if not awesome) course for free you can check on the Laracast webpage with host Jeffrey Way that is explaining all of that with a simple example with cards.

#### Source-code

```
<!-- I consider the variable you return in the view to be $articles -->

@foreach ($articles as $article)

    <h1>{{ $article->title }}</h1>

    <!-- some more HTML code as you wish to display it -->

@endforeach
```

#### Documentation

[Laravel 5.3 : Blade](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/blade).

[Laracast : Laravel From Scratch (Fetching datas)](https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-5-from-scratch/episodes/7).